# File location of phtml file of backend admin page

Tags: magento, directory

I installed an extension to add custom fields to customer registration form.I want to add some option value in dropdown menu box of input validation in backend admin page..could you plz tell me the path of the folder where can I find the phtml file which is responsible for that part ?

-Thanks.

Comment: RESOLVED: I got the file at magento/app/code/community/Custom/Attributemanager/Block/Edit/Tab/Main.php .

Answer (score 0):

The files you are looking for are in:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template
```

But just changing the .phtml file won't do the job. The customer model itself should be extended to provide for your extra field. Therefore i highly recommend you to write a module for this instead of altering Magento core code. This to make sure that you can still use updates in the future.

Writing such an module requires more in depth knowledge of Magento. For more information on custom adminhtml see [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/changing_the_adminhtml_template).

For information on extending the core functionality look [here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento).

If you don't feel like programming this all yourself take a look at customer attribute modules on Magento Connect.